# install Tensorflow 1.0 on windows by Anaconda error

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

By following the instructions on [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows), I tried to install cpu-only version Tensorflow by Anaconda. However, the 4th step

```
(tensorflow)C:> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl
```

outputs an error:

```
tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. Could anyone tell me the reason behind this?
```

Comment: What is the output of python --version and pip -V?

Comment: python 3.5 and pip 9, I have solved the problem, please refer to the answer from @Beomi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command on the website is currently wrong. Replace `x86_64` at the end of the URL with `amd64` to get the correct command:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Alternatively you can use the following simpler command to install the latest CPU version:

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: However, I have solved the problem, in Anaconda, just by `pip install tensorflow` . Your second command seems not working.

Comment: What error do you get? `pip install tensorflow` is generally the simplest way, but the URL version should work as well.

Comment: URL version works well, I mean the second command output the same error as "... is not a supported wheel...". Anyway, the problem is solved and Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems could be one of this:

1. your python version is not Python3.5
2. Your system is not x64 windows.

So you can change install method below.

You can install `tensorflow` with `pip` direct  like this:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

but this works only pip version > 9,
if you're using pip version under 9, you have to upgrade pip first.

you can upgrade your pip with this:

```
pip install -U pip
```

> if you've installed python for all user, you might run this code with administrator account.

Comment: thanks, I have solved the problem, in Anaconda, just "pip install tensorflow", and it worked. My python is 3.5 and pip is >9. I just wonder the reason. Thanks anyway.